# Se puede generar un video con audio y videos clip con ffmpeg

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, video

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual tengo que generar de una serie de video clip un único video de x duración, me recomendaron utilizar la ffmpeg pero no se si se pueda crear y si es posible como seria la estructura, ya que tengo entendido que se necesita un archivo con una estructura en la cual se establezca la ruta en este caso videos y audio, estoy trabajando en codeigniter con php 7, ya logro ejecutar el ffmpeg para cambiar el formato de un video.

La cuestión es la siguiente, desde una base de datos traigo la lista de la ruta de los vídeos su duración y peso, igual con los audios, la cosa es como puedo hacer para crear el video con ffmpeg a partir de esto.

Comment: si, se puede. los videos todos usan la misma resolusion y codec tanto en audio como video?

Comment: pues hay vídeos que difieren un poco en resolucion no tanto, pero el formato es el mismo en mp4 los audios estan en formato mp3, pero el archivo como estaria?? como seria la estructura y cuales son los comanados para esto?

Comment: bueno, puedo responderte pero el probelma es que habria que editar la pregunta y sacar todo lo de codeigniter, php, javascript etc porque un problema es concatenar videos con ffmpeg y otro problema diferente es invocarlo desde php (o cualquier otra plataforma).. si no te molesta que edite la pregunta, puedo responderte.

Comment: pues adelante, puedes editarla